# Heading sentences without page numbers centered in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}` type of document and `\tableofcontents` to generate the table of contents. I wanted the table of contents like shown in the image. [image]
To be particular, I wanted the sentences like "Study material", "Practical manual" and "Other supporting documents" to be present at the center of the pages, along with table of contents without page numbers. Just for the sake of drawing the attention to the core, the above three headings are highlighted using red color. I want them to be in black color itself.

Comment: The trailing "with section [why singular??] and subsections" strings after each and every chapter-level entry seems rather redundant. Can it be omitted? Do the lines "Study material", "Practical manual", and "Other supporting documents" correspond to `\part`-level directives? Another concern: The page numbers don't appear to be right-aligned -- is this intentional?

Comment: The image that is presented here is for the sake of understanding the problem. I created the above image using MS word and hence the page numbers that are misaligned should be ignored. The sections (sorry for showing it as section) and subsections are generated without any problem. My main requirement is to have the lines like "Study material", "Practical Manual" and "Other supporting documents" like shown in the image. And lines like "Study material", "Practical Manual" and "Other supporting documents" are not \part level directives.

Comment: You might define three unnumbered parts with title on its own page, and add them to the table of contents.

Comment: You wrote, "And lines like "Study material", "Practical Manual" and "Other supporting documents" are not `\part` level directives." Please don't tell us what these lines *are  not*; it would be far more helpful to state what they *are*. E.g., are they just center-set lines in the Table of Contents -- with no corresponding material in the body of the document? Conversely, if these lines do correspond to something in the document, what would this "something" be?

Comment: @Mico The lines like "Study material", "Practical Manual" and "Other supporting documents" are just center-set lines in the Table of Contents -- with no corresponding material in the body of the document. The font sizes of these lines should be large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\begin{center}\Large\bfseries Study material\end{center}}

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Another}

\addtocontents{toc}{\begin{center}\Large\bfseries Practical manual\end{center}}

\chapter{Practical introduction}

\end{document}
```

Adjust the fonts to suit.

The `\addtocontents{<file>}{<text>}` macro adds the `<text>` to the `<file>` which in your case is `toc` for the table of contents file.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Worked perfectly as I wanted it.